# Accessing fields with Python CGI FieldStorage from a JQuery AJAX call

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, cgi

I have written some JQuery that makes an ajax call to a Python script.  I've been successful in passing strings back and forth between them, but I'm getting weird behaviour from the CGI FieldStorage object that I'm using to get the input in the Python script.  I've also managed to send a simple object with key/value pairs, like this:

```
deptObj = { one : '1', two : '2'};

$.ajax({
    data: deptObj,
    url: "simple.py",
    success: function(result) { console.log("Success!"); console.log(result); },
    error: function(request, error) { console.log("Error"); console.log(request); }
});
```

Here is my python script, simple.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import cgi
import cgitb

print "Content-type: application/json\n\n" 
cgitb.enable() # display error messages in web browser

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

print json.dumps(fs.keys())
```

When I run the javascript, it correctly prints out the keys in my object, i.e. `["two", "one"]` (I'm not sure why they're reversed).  I can also get the corresponding values by replacing the last line of simple.py with something like `print json.dumps(fs["one"].value)`.

However, when I try to make a multi-level object (an object within an object), I get weird behaviour.  For example, I kept the deptObj that I had already created, then passed in `data: { departments: deptObj}` to the ajax call.  Then, when I tell simple.py to print out the keys, the result is `["departments[two]", "departments[one]"]` instead of what I would expect, `["departments"]`.  Then, since "departments" is apparently not a key, I get a KeyError when I try `print json.dumps(fs["departments"].value)`, while `print json.dumps(fs["departments[one]"].value)` gives me a result of 1.

According to the [documentation for FieldStorage](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html), "the fields, accessed through form[key], are themselves instances of FieldStorage", so I thought that my FieldStorage object would have a "departments" key whose value is another FieldStorage object containing the keys "one" and "two".  However, this doesn't seem to be true.  How do I form a multi-level Javascript object and access it in my python script using FieldStorage?

Answer (score 1):

This is just jQuery being silly. You should set `traditional: true` in your `$.ajax` call.

Comment: This seems to have partially solved the problem - now `fs.keys()` gives me "departments", but I still can't figure out how to access "one" and "two".  `fs["departments"].value` shows up as `[object Object]` in my Web Inspector console, without any fields. `fs.getlist("departments")` gives me something similar, `["[object Object]"]`. `len(fs["departments"])` gives me an error that says "AttributeError: MiniFieldStorage instance has no attribute 'len'".  Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried `fs["departments"].keys()`, which gives me the error "MiniFieldStorage instance has no attribute 'keys'".

Comment: You're just confusing yourself by dumping back to json and using the browser console. Put a breakpoint in your Python script and examine it there.

Comment: What do you mean by "putting a breakpoint" in my script?  I tried just printing out the python object (not as JSON), but where would this output go, if not to to my website?  I'm looking at the apache2 error log but it doesn't say anything useful.

Comment: You still haven't stated what you are trying to achieve. As I say, you are confusing yourself by posting to Python, serializing to JSON, returning to the client, then examining in the web inspector: there are too many steps, it's impossible to tell at which step things are going wrong. For debugging, check one step at a time: from the Python, log to disk instead of returning; then, ignore the POST and just return what you think you want, and inspect that, and so on. One obvious issue is that you're never deserializing the JSON back in the browser, though.

Comment: I stated exactly what I'm trying to achieve in my original question.  If something in it is confusing, you should ask me a specific question about it. Thanks for your help, but I am still confused by your debugging instructions and had already spent too long on this.  In the end I decided to avoid the whole problem and just use a single-level object (I had to concatenate some of my array data into a string to do this).

Answer (score 0):

This will not strictly answer your question but I hope it answers the goal rather than the specifics of what you asked.  I'm sorry if it's not what you wanted.

jQuery passing the Ajax request whose content type is (by default) `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` (taken from the [jQuery (v1.0 and later) documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)).

There are a few ways to get the JSON into your python script from the JavaScript.  The first is to explicitly make a form field and pass in the 'stringified' JSON structure which you can then parse at the other end.  Another is to try and reverse engineer how jQuery is encoding the JSON string and pick apart the encoded fields into a JSON string (which sounds painful).

There is (in my opinion) a better way, which passes the content type as JSON straight away by specifying the content type to be JSON in the Ajax query.  For example, changing your jQuery Ajax call to:

```
deptObj = { one : '1', two : '2'};

$.ajax({
    data: deptObj,
    type: "POST",
    url: "simple.py",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(result) { console.log("Success!"); console.log(result); },
    error: function(request, error) { console.log("Error"); console.log(request); }
});
```

(that is, adding the `type` to `'POST'` and adding the `dataType` to `'json'`).  And the corresponding Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable() # display error messages in web browser

print "Content-type: application/json\n\n" 
print json.dumps( json.load( sys.stdin ) )
```

yields what I believe to be your desired result.